# Ubuntu don't remember my brightness settings

Tags: brightness

I installed Ubuntu 13.04. I notice that when I lower the brightness there is a lowest brightness point and when I lower further than that the brightness will increase. And why every time I restart the computer the brightness value goes to default.

Comment: And what is the question here? Please ask a question, not simply describe a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```